# Deleting record with lowest ID

Tags: mysql

When I type this query in MySQL :

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID = ( SELECT Min( ID ) FROM myTable )
```

I get the following error message :

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'myTable' for update in FROM clause
```

What is the problem ?

What is the right equivalent ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically in MySQL you can't do an update on a table which you use in the `SELECT` part. For detail you could check this behaviour which is documented at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

In theory every `DELETE` is an `UPDATE` so that's why you get this error.

You could simply do following:

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
ORDER BY my_id
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Minimum ID may not be 1. What in that case ?

Comment: 1 refers to number of records that you want to delete. It is not related with ID.

Answer (score 5):

try

`DELETE FROM myTable ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;`

Comment: @amit LIMIT 1 does not mean we are looking for an ID that has the value 1. It means limiting the result set to one row.

Answer (score 4):

That's because in MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.

Read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
This behaviour is documented at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Instead of nested subquery, execute the operation in two parts, or alternatively use a simple where clause.

Try :

```
$min_id = SELECT Min( ID ) FROM myTable
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID = $min_id
```

Now you shall not get any error.

Cheers..!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM myTable ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: In mySql, You can't refer myTable inside the subquery that was the whole problem....

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM myTable ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```